# Unexpected command line behavior using commas in Windows/DOS batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos

Today, I wanted to test if filenames can contain commas and stumbled upon something else while opening `cmd` and trying these three tests:

```
echo a,b>a
```

This works as supposed (writes `a,b` to the file named `a`)

```
echo a>a,b
```

Does just the same! What happens here gets a bit clearer with the third test:

```
echo a>file,b this is a test
```

This will create a file named `file` containing `a,b this is a test`.

Now, three questions arise for me:

1. What is the explanation for this? If someone asked me, I would've guessed the comma separates commands or filenames, e.g. I would've expected the second test to create two files named `a` and `b`.
2. Is this behaviour documented somewhere?
3. Is it a `cmd` specific Windows extension or has it been like this since good old DOS times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expected behaviour as `,;=<space><tab>` are delimiters for parameters.
If you put the code into a batch file without `echo OFF` you will see

test.bat

```
echo a,b>a
echo a>a,b
echo a>file,b this is a test
```

Output

```
C:\temp>test.bat
C:\temp>echo a,b 1>a
C:\temp>echo a,b 1>a
C:\temp>echo a,b this is a test 1>file
```

After a redirection, only the next token is relevant, the rest is part of the normal line content.
It's unimportant where the redirection occurs in a line.
But there is the rule that when more than one redirection exists for the same stream, the last one will win.

```
> file.txt echo hello> nul world > con
```

This will result in `hello world` at the console.

Btw. There is still an obscure behaviour with redirection and lines extended by carets (multilines).

```
echo one two three^
 four
```

Result: `one two three four`

But

```
echo one two >con three^
 four
```

Result: `one two  four`

Comment: imo `00h` and `FFh` are also valid delimiters.

Comment: `0x00` will break/stops the parser, `0xff` is handled often as a delimiter, but I can remember that it's not always work

Comment: yes you are right. `0x00` does never work and `0xFF` doesn't work reliable (XP & Win8).

Answer (score 1):

The comma is a standard delimiter in batch as well as `; <space> = <tab>`  and everything after the comma is taken as another parameter to echo and only one parameter is taken for the redirection. You can try to enclose `a,b` in quotes and this should change the behaviour of the output and produce a,b file. You can also escape the delimiters with `^` - `echo a>a^,b`
You can try also `echo a>a=b` - it will be the same.